# ChartJS - Time graph from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am returning a JSON to my view and I want to parse the date on a line graph, but I am having some issues with adding dates using ChartJS.

This is my JSON format: (can be changed)

```
[
  { "y": 4, "x": "2017-01-01" },
  { "y": 0, "x": "2017-01-02" },
  { "y": 9, "x": "2017-01-03" },
  { "y": 0, "x": "2017-01-04" },
  { "y": 14, "x": "2017-01-05" }
]
```

I tried this but keep getting random timestamps

```
data: {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
    data: [{
      y: 0,
      x: new Date('2017,03,01')
    }, {
      y: 1,
      x: new Date('2017,03,02')
    }, {
      y: 2,
      x: new Date('2017,03,03')
    }],
    label: "test",
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to put the correct dates on the x-axis and place the values on the y-axis? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, why aren't you just mapping JSON into `data`? The values in the datastring in your JSON will work with `Date`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in Date initialization:

```
new Date('2017,03,01')
```

should be replaced by

```
new Date(2017,03,01)
```

(without quotes), because '2017,03,01' is a string with an invalid date format.
You can initialize a Date object with a string with the following format (the same you have as input):

```
 new Date('2017-03-01')
```

In order to trasform the json of your input you can write a function like this:

```
 var input = [{"y":4,"x":"2017-01-01"},
              {"y":0,"x":"2017-01-02"},
              {"y":9,"x":"2017-01-03"}, 
              {"y":0,"x":"2017-01-04"},
              {"y":14,"x":"2017-01-05"}];

 var data = input.map(function(item) {
      return {x: new Date(item["x"]), y: item["y"]};
 });
```

and pass data to your graph.

Answer (score 0):

Use the json data as is, but tell chart.js that the x axis is time.  [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/microMerlin/52k1xmj8/1/)

```
options: {
 "scales": {
  "xAxes": [{
    "type": "time"
  }]
 }
}
```

See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html for more time axis configuration options.  Especially the parser (tick) property, if using various time and date formats.